# how to save the output to a.txt, i have some error

Tags: python-2.7

i am practice save to txt but i get some error.

my code
http://dpaste.com/3MR3TZF

you can see the 65th :

```
f.write(tag+"\n")
```

i get the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character`,

but i allready # -*- coding: utf-8 -* in my code 1th

the second error is

74th , `d = float (c)/((a+b)-c)`
75th , `f.write(d+"\n")`

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

how to slove it?

Comment: "a" must be a string check if it really is

Comment: if you want all the output just redirect the output instead of writing to a file like `python test.py > data.txt`

Comment: @sameerasy can you say more how to do? why python test.py > data.txt

Comment: are you running the file on the terminal? just see redirection of output